# Where is "the line" for copyleft licenses

Tags: licensing

Where exactly is "the line" between needed to copy a copyleft license and not?
For example, I am writing a non GNU GPL program that uses git. 
I do not mean that I use git to write it, I mean, git is actually a vital part of what the program does. The code itself calls git.

Can I do this without needing to copyleft? 
Can I distribute git with my program? Or do I have to require users to install it separately?

I know that a "fork" of git would be copyleft and just using git to write code does not. What about in-between?

More specifically:
my program uses git to push files to remotes. This is more lightweight then a simple upload cause it only sends a diff. 
I don't need to patch git or change at all, but I would like to package git and the Unix libraries it comes with (for windows) simply for simplicity.

Comment: You should explain more how and what for exactly your code will use `git` . Do you have to *patch* `git` ? What for ? or are you siùply forking ` git`  processes?

Comment: Sure. Its really simple, my program uses git to push files to remotes. This is more lightweight then a simple upload cause it only sends a diff. I don't need to patch git at all, but I would like to package git and the Unix libraries it comes with (for windows) simply for simplicity.

Comment: You should edit your question to improve it, not comment it.

Comment: Did you consider making your own program using `git`  some GPLv3 free software?

Comment: I don't have that ability. I'm doing this for a company that won't publish anything GPL.

Comment: Then be sure to cover your ass, and perhaps ask the lawyers of your company and at the very least your manager or client; I believe you could begin to explain to your manager/company why they should publish the code under GPL. It is a long journey.

Comment: Are you employed by the company or a contractor of it? Under which legal system (in which country)?

Comment: Does your program depend on git to do something vital? Or is it calling git just as a convenience. If it is something vital, it seems better to find another way that is compatible with your license.

Comment: BTW, if this is software you are making for a company as an employee, it is (quite often) not *your* software, but *the software of the company*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it depends on legal subtleties that have never been tested in court.

Answer (score 3):

It is a grey area (BTW beware I am quite a GPL enthusiast so I am biased); I guess you mean GPLv3 (but perhaps git is GPLv2 and then details are different)

**[GPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html)** is so called a "viral license" (I dislike that expression because it looks negative,but it is not), or (much better wording) a strong [copyleft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft) license. It **has a [FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html)** which answers some of your concerns. GPL is about [**free** -or *libre*-  **software**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) ([**freedom**](https://www.fsf.org/) of speech, not "free as in beer" i.e. freeware or gratis)

I won't repeat the FAQ. What matter is not only how you use GPL, but also somehow your intents. For instance, if you publish a GPLv3 patch to a GPLv3 program which is only designed to communicate -using some *unique* protocol peculiar to your application!- with a particular program of yours, *some people* believe that your program should be GPLv3-ed. If the protocol is documented and used by *several* applications things are different.

<sup>So linking (with `ld`) is not the only way to have some *derived work* (or *covered work*) from the point of view of GPL. Things might be more complex.</sup>

Ultimately, **it is a legal question** (so *off-topic* here), and in several legal systems it has to be specifically tested in a court.

BTW, you could **ask your lawyer**, and *you might ask the FSF*. Of course, the FSF has a "biased" (at least strong & specific) view on software, but it also does have experts on the licensing field and it has some lists or forums to discuss that. But read the GPLv3 and its FAQ first.

The point is that your **user should keep his/her freedom to *upgrade*** (or *improve*) **`git`** and that should be *easy* for him/her (so making that easy is your technical concern). At the very least, you should document how your program is exactly using `git`  and of course provide a mean to replace `git` by an upgraded version (perhaps installed *elsewhere* and invoked as a different command than just `git`, e.g. `$HOME/bin/git-patched-by-basile`, so at least the command line invoking `git`  should be somehow user-configurable in a documented way etc...).

If you package `git`  on some *physical* media, be sure (for courtesy to your users) to package its source code also. If you are providing some network downloading of your software, again have the courtesy to give the URL to `git`  and to *recommend* some version and to *explain* how your user could upgrade/reconfigure the `git`  used by your program.

At last, did you consider making your own program some free software? That would solve a lot of questions (especially if you care to choose a license compatible with the GPL version used by `git`)

If you work for a company, be sure to inform and ask your managers/clients and the lawyers that you do things right. Don't violate the GPL and make them be aware of any issues! Don't even try to *interpret* the GPL yourself (but *explain what you understand about the GPL* to managers and lawyers and clients and any responsible stakeholder). **Ask the company** (owning the software), e.g. **your boss/your client/your lawyer**. If possible *try to **explain your boss why making your code a free software under GPL is better** for the company*. This is a long journey.

**I am not a lawyer** and you probably are not neither. But you have ethical concerns, you don't want to do illegal things, you don't want to put your comapny in trouble, so you should not hide any potential issues (e.g. from your manager, if you are an employee, or from your client, if you are a consultant).

If you are a developer employed by some company, don't even try to solve licensing issues yourself, and ask your manager! (Details are strongly specific to the legal system of your country, your work contract, etc...) Surely don't hide (neither from your boss, nor from your users) the fact that the program is running `git`  and make user-configurable the exact name or command-line or path invoking the `git` program

Comment: This has way too much GPL-fanboying in it.

Comment: My first sentence mentioned that I am a GPL fan. So what? The OP question is legal advice and probably off-topic, and we don't know enough details to give a good precise and specific advice.

Comment: Then vote to close it, instead of posting "I love GPL" as an answer.

Comment: My answer is not essentially I love the GPL. It has some more general and specific advices and opinions.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's a judgement call.  The following are the kinds of questions that will be asked when you get taken to court:

- Does your software directly compete with git, or is it incidental to its use?  In other words, is the elevator pitch of your software something like, "It syncs changes to files between different computers?"
- Does your software still work, just with reduced functionality, if you didn't install git?
- Could a user replace git with, say, a shell script that calls `rsync` without changing your code?
- Can you upgrade your software and git independently?

If the answers to all these questions aren't *clearly* on the safe side, you need to get lawyers involved.  If your company doesn't want to GPL their software, they understand that incurs the cost of limiting their ability to incorporate GPL software in their products.  You need to clearly spell out the cost of alternatives.  They might surprise you.  Even Microsoft has contributed some open source software.

Comment: Don't see how competition is relevant. Lots of software syncs file changes and performs diffs without having anything to do with Git code. If your software is dependent on a GPL component, then the license of that component gives you a requirement to also distribute your source code. It doesn't say anything about competition.

Comment: I mention competition because it's a measure of how much it depends on git for its central functionality and improves upon its functionality.  If software competes with git but doesn't use git, who cares?  It matters very much when you're depending on git for your implementation.

Comment: Competition doesn't measure dependency. For example, if you use Qt to make an application, it doesn't mean your application "competes with" Qt. On the other hand, if it needs Qt to run, then it does depend on Qt and so you'd need to consider the license terms for Qt (LGPL or commercial license, take your pick)

Comment: Which is more of a derivative work?  A file-syncing utility that builds on git, or a web browser that uses git to sync bookmarks?  It's not the only measure, but it *is* a significant one.